# Visual Studio can't add service reference - invalid XML

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I'm trying to add a service reference using Visual Studio 2022 and Clearbooks API.

https://secure.clearbooks.co.uk/api/accounting/wsdl/ <-- this is the URL I'm trying to use.

The problem is that, when I try to add it, I get this error message:

"There was an error generating the XML document."

I tried downloading the XML file itself and seeing it in VS, it appears that VS finds certain attributes invalid (e.g. "base", "minOccurs", "maxOccurs").

Is this something that I can solve within Visual Studio, or do I have to contact Clearbooks to get it resolved?

Comment: Is your project .NET/.NET Core or .NET Framework? I get this error when trying to add it to a .NET project (which apparently is more detailed): https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9Bz3.png  Maybe that helps...

Comment: .NET Framework.